# Azure DevOps Azure PowerShell task output variable - Unable to pass value to third stage

Tags: azure, powershell, yaml, devops

I am trying to pass variables between stages. I was successfully able to pass values to immediate next stage, but after that the variables are blank. I tried all the ways to get this, but failing

```
stages:
- stage: InitialStage
  jobs:
  - job: StandAlone
    displayName: Required Stand Alone Job
    steps:
    - bash: |
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=doThing;isOutput=true]Yes"
      name: bash_test

- stage: SecondStage
  jobs:
  - job:
    displayName: SecondStage
    variables:
      variable1: $[ stageDependencies.InitialStage.StandAlone.outputs['bash_test.doThing'] ]
      
    steps:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      name: test
      inputs:
        script: |
          echo "$(variable1)"

- stage: ThirdStage
  jobs:
  - job:
    displayName: ThirdStage
    variables:
      variable1: $[ stageDependencies.InitialStage.StandAlone.outputs['bash_test.doThing'] ]
      
    steps:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      name: test
      inputs:
        script: |
          echo "$(variable1)"
```

The echo at stage SecondStage will give value, but ThirdStage it is blank, I am having a doubt either we can access a variable only in immediate stage or else I am doing something wrong, any help on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

In order to pass variable to the another stage you need to add `isOutput=true`

See the example as shown below;

```
- task: Bash@3
  name:  setprojectName
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline' 
    script: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=projectNameGlobal;isOutput=true]$(echo $(Build.Repository.Name)| sed 's|.*/||')"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=projectName]$(echo $(Build.Repository.Name)| sed 's|.*/||')"
```

projectName is only available the stage where variable populated but projectNameGlobal is available in next stage also.

Also see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-stage)

Option 2:

```
## azure-pipelines.yml
stages:

- stage: one
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
          filePath: 'script-a.sh'
      name: setvar
    - bash: |
       echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=skipsubsequent;isOutput=true]true"
      name: skipstep

- stage: two
  jobs:
  - job: B
    variables:
      - name: StageSauce
        value: $[ stageDependencies.one.A.outputs['setvar.sauce'] ]
      - name: skipMe
        value: $[ stageDependencies.one.A.outputs['skipstep.skipsubsequent'] ]
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        filePath: 'script-b.sh'
      name: fileversion
      env:
        StageSauce: $(StageSauce) # predefined in variables section
        skipMe: $(skipMe) # predefined in variables section
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo 'Hello inline version'
          echo $(skipMe) 
          echo $(StageSauce)
```

In above option you can see how to use one variable where populated by any of the prior stages

Comment: I have already specified isOutput=true, and variable doThing is available in stage: SecondStage, but not at stage: ThirdStage

Comment: see edited solution to use variable into any of the upcoming stages

Comment: @KağanMersin: The question itself says value cannot be passed to the third stage and not to the second stage, when you confirms something works, please test it prior posting, even if you copy from official sources. I have also faced same issue previously and literally nothing will work when you need to pass output variables from stage 1 to stage 3